# Installing an electrical outlet in my attic?

Tags: attic, junction-box

So before it snows and gets colder outside I would like to install an electrical outlet in my attic. I'm gonna hook up a light to it. In my attic there is some wire running along the beams, could I splice it and add a junction box and then hook up a the electrical outlet to it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Some wiring", eh?

Comment: I think it's 12/2 electrical wire.

Comment: Step two: investigate where it goes and what devices it supplies. Chances are you can do as you describe, but we can't answer with what little you've provided. Edit your question to add details.

Answer (score 1):

*If* the cable is feeding a typical residential circuit, and *if* it's not already at legal capacity (which is fairly flexible in many cases), and *if* there's no other weirdness at play, yes.

If you're not lucky enough to have two feet of slack you may need to use two junction boxes. Cut the wire between two boxes and pull it into each of them. Run a new length of wire between, and splice in your new outlet leg from one box. It's more or less blacks to blacks and whites to whites. Junction boxes must remain accessible. Secure all cables appropriately (and within a foot of each box).

Comment: Ok thanks. I figured I would have to add 2 because I don't think there is any slack.

Comment: Be careful which cable, it might be a switched, instead of always hot.

Comment: Does "the circuit supplies bathroom, laundry room or kitchen receptacles" count as a weirdness?

Comment: @MikeD then you might as well add 2 in respectable locations for lights.  Consider non-incandescent lights, nothing is more annoying than nailing an incandescent bulb with stuff or your head, and breaking the bulb and plunging into darkness.  Or the kid stacks right up to the bulb and the bulb burns a hole in your stuff.   My preference is fluorescent fixtures at the apes, run off flexible cords, which are legal when supplying luminaires.

Comment: I checked I believe it's connected to a ceiling light and some outlets.